# Showing image depending on variable value PHP (FPDF)

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I'm new here and I've been looking for an answer regarding this issue for awhile but I can't figure out a way to solve this.

My project consists of a calculator capable of saving a result and let the user export it as a PDF file if he wishes to. 
Now, the problem is, I want to showcase an image on the PDF file depending on the result: eg. If the result is M1 then it shows an image linked to M1 and so on.
Is there any way to do this?

I'm using PHP, MYSQL Database to save the results & inputs, and fPDF. Any help would be apreciated.
Thank you.

```
    function Header(){

        global $first;
        global $second;
        global $userinput;
        global $client;
        global $project;
        global $obs;
        global $vao;
        global $perfil;
        global $valuep; //this is the final result that needs to be linked to an image
        global $lastname;
        global $firstname;
        global $lastname;
        global $email;
        global $address;
        global $country;
        global $state;
        global $phone;
        global $date;


        // Select Arial bold 15
        $this->AddFont('Raleway-Regular','','Raleway-Regular.php');
        $this->AddFont('Raleway-Bold','','Raleway-Bold.php');
        $this->SetFont('Raleway-Regular','',10);

        $this->SetFont('Raleway-Bold','',10);
        $this->Cell(22 ,5,'Name: ' . $firstname, '' .$lastname,0,0);
        $this->Cell(20 ,5,'Email: ' . $email,0,1);
        $this->Cell(20 ,5,'Phone: ' . $phone,0,1);
        $this->Cell(20 ,5,'Website: ' . $state,0,1);



        $this->Image('headerimage.jpg',160,15,30);

        $this->Cell(100,0,'',0,0);
        $this->Ln(5);

        $this->SetFont('Raleway-Regular','',10);
        $this->SetFillColor(0,0,0);
        $this->SetDrawColor(255,255,255);


        $this->Cell(25 ,5,"Project Name: " . $project ,0,1);
        $this->Cell(24.5,5,'Client: ' .$client,1,0);
        $this->Cell(25,5,'Date: ' . $date,0,1);

        //

        $this->Cell(0 ,5,'',0,1);


        //

        $this->Cell(190,0.3,'','T',0,'',true);

        $this->Cell(0 ,5,'',0,1);


         $this->SetFont('Raleway-Bold','',12);

        $this->Cell(85 ,5,'Inputs ',0,0);
        $this->Cell(25 ,5,'Span Details ',0,1);

        $this->Cell(0 ,5,'',0,1);
        $this->SetFont('Raleway-Regular','',11);
        $this->Cell(190,0.3,'','T',0,'',true);
        $this->Cell(0 ,5,'',0,1);
        $this->Cell(25 ,5,'Name of Span: ' . $vao,0,0);

        $this->Cell(0 ,5,'',0,1);
        $this->Cell(0 ,5,'',0,1);
        $this->Cell(85 ,5,'Wind Action: ' .$perfil . '' . $userinput . ' kN/m2]',0,0);

         $this->SetFont('Raleway-Regular','',11);
         $this->Cell(30 ,5,'Height: ' . $first . ' m',0,0);
         $this->Cell(30 ,5,'Width: ' . $second . ' m',0,1);

        //
         $this->Cell(0 ,5,'',0,1);
        //
         $this->Cell(190,0.3,'','T',0,'',true);
         $this->Cell(0 ,5,'',0,1);
         $this->SetFont('Raleway-Regular','',11);
         $this->SetFont('Raleway-Bold','',12);
         $this->Cell(25 ,5,'Solution ',0,1);
         $this->SetFont('Raleway-Regular','',11);
         $this->Cell(0 ,5,'',0,1);
         $this->Cell(190,0.3,'','T',0,'',true);
         $this->Cell(0 ,5,'',0,1);

         $this->Cell(25 ,5,'Final result: ' . $valuep,0,1); //image here next to the text
        //
        $this->Cell(0 ,5,'',0,1);
        //

          $this->Cell(0 ,5,'',0,1);
          $this->Cell(0 ,5,'',0,1);
          $this->Cell(0 ,5,'',0,1);

          $this->SetFont('Raleway-Bold','',12);
          $this->Cell(25 ,5,'Observations: ',0,1);
          $this->SetFillColor(255,255,255);

    }



    function Footer(){


   // Go to 1.5 cm from bottom
    $this->SetY(-15);
    // Select Arial italic 8
    $this->SetFont('Raleway-Bold','',5);
    // Print centered page number
    $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo(),0,0,'C');
    $this->Cell(25,5,"Vestibulum placerat lorem venenatis nulla tempor maximus a ut elit.",0,0,'R');
    } }


$pdf = new PDF('P','mm','A4'); $pdf->AliasNbPages('{pages}');

$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true,5); $pdf->AddPage();


$pdf->SetFont('Raleway-Regular','',10); $text=str_repeat('' .$obs,1); $pdf->Write(5,$text); $pdf->SetDrawColor(255,255,255);



$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: I am sorry I didn't get the point. Which result are you referring to ? can you please elaborate more on what your expected output is ? You can even use visual aids if you want.

Comment: I can't upload images yet so I have to post it on [imgur](https://imgur.com/9WFrKuu) Blurred out for spoilers.

Comment: Ok. If you can't upload images then please format your description in such a way that you show us what your expected output is so that it'll be clear for us as to what help you actually need.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how many results you will possibly get and do the pictures vary.

Since you are using mySQL, I suggest to make a table with all the results and images in it.

Then read out the result and voila you have the image attached to it.

Comment: The images do vary. Example: If the result is, let's say, a turtle, the image displayed should be a turtle also. I've tried doing that but I'm still a bit lost.

Comment: You still have to make a connection between the answer and the image. Best to do it in a database. The other solution would be to name the images exactly as the answer and read the image folder with glob().